# Installing driver for touchscreen

Tags: drivers, touchscreen

I got a touchscreen monitor and want to install the driver to my Ubuntu 20.04. The driver software is TouchKit. In the installation guide, this is what written:

```
Rebuild the TouchKit driver.
3.1) Locate the extracted directory. And go to the subdirectory
/touchkit/include then type make new
3.2) change the directory to /touchkit then type make all
The touchKit driver will be rebuild. ( Some packages must be
installed and well configured ).
3.3) type make install to begin to install at the same directory /touchkit
```

At step 3.1, I got the following error:

```
rm -f configSTR.h configSTR.mak configINT.h configINT.mak touch.tcl
tclsh ../utility/tcl2h.tcl configSTR.tcl > configSTR.h
/bin/sh: 1: tclsh: not found
make: *** [Makefile:20: configSTR.h] Error 127
```

Is this error due to the installation software or something on my Ubuntu? I have emailed the seller, but I thought to ask here as well.

Update: here is the `Makefile` file which, I assume, is executed when I run `make new`

```
TCL     = tclsh
TCL2H   = ../utility/tcl2h.tcl
TCL2SH  = ../utility/tcl2sh.tcl
TCL2MAK = ../utility/tcl2mak.tcl
INI2TCL = ../utility/ini2tcl.tcl

TARGET  = configSTR.h configSTR.mak \
        configINT.h configINT.mak   \
        touch.tcl
            
all auto rebuild:   $(TARGET)

new:    clean all

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET)

%.h: %.tcl $(TCL2H)
    $(TCL) $(TCL2H) $< > $@

%.sh: %.tcl $(TCL2SH)
    $(TCL) $(TCL2SH) $< > $@

%.mak: %.tcl $(TCL2MAK)
    $(TCL) $(TCL2MAK) $< > $@

%.tcl: %.ini $(INI2TCL)
    $(TCL) $(INI2TCL) $< > $@
```

If someone could advise what stuff in there is specific to Ubuntu, or what is related to the driver software or points me to a certain direction? Thanks.

Update: so I have figured out and got pass Step 3.1. At Step 3.2, I got the following errors:

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c', needed by 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:232: archscripts] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:25: build_module] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/userxxx/touchscreen/Ubuntu6.06/touchkit/usb'
make: *** [Makefile:57: all] Error 1
```

Here is the `Makefile` for Step 3.2:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
PHONY += posttest

ifeq ($(KBUILD_VERBOSE),1)
  posttest_verbose = -v
else
  posttest_verbose =
endif

ifeq ($(CONFIG_64BIT),y)
  posttest_64bit = -y
else
  posttest_64bit = -n
endif

reformatter = $(srctree)/arch/x86/tools/objdump_reformat.awk
chkobjdump = $(srctree)/arch/x86/tools/chkobjdump.awk

quiet_cmd_posttest = TEST    $@
      cmd_posttest = ($(OBJDUMP) -v | $(AWK) -f $(chkobjdump)) || $(OBJDUMP) -d -j .text $(objtree)/vmlinux | $(AWK) -f $(reformatter) | $(obj)/insn_decoder_test $(posttest_64bit) $(posttest_verbose)

quiet_cmd_sanitytest = TEST    $@
      cmd_sanitytest = $(obj)/insn_sanity $(posttest_64bit) -m 1000000

posttest: $(obj)/insn_decoder_test vmlinux $(obj)/insn_sanity
    $(call cmd,posttest)
    $(call cmd,sanitytest)

hostprogs-y += insn_decoder_test insn_sanity

# -I needed for generated C source and C source which in the kernel tree.
HOSTCFLAGS_insn_decoder_test.o := -Wall -I$(objtree)/arch/x86/lib/ -I$(srctree)/arch/x86/include/uapi/ -I$(srctree)/arch/x86/include/ -I$(srctree)/arch/x86/lib/ -I$(srctree)/include/uapi/

HOSTCFLAGS_insn_sanity.o := -Wall -I$(objtree)/arch/x86/lib/ -I$(srctree)/arch/x86/include/ -I$(srctree)/arch/x86/lib/ -I$(srctree)/include/

# Dependencies are also needed.
$(obj)/insn_decoder_test.o: $(srctree)/arch/x86/lib/insn.c $(srctree)/arch/x86/lib/inat.c $(srctree)/arch/x86/include/asm/inat_types.h $(srctree)/arch/x86/include/asm/inat.h $(srctree)/arch/x86/include/asm/insn.h $(objtree)/arch/x86/lib/inat-tables.c

$(obj)/insn_sanity.o: $(srctree)/arch/x86/lib/insn.c $(srctree)/arch/x86/lib/inat.c $(srctree)/arch/x86/include/asm/inat_types.h $(srctree)/arch/x86/include/asm/inat.h $(srctree)/arch/x86/include/asm/insn.h $(objtree)/arch/x86/lib/inat-tables.c

HOST_EXTRACFLAGS += -I$(srctree)/tools/include
hostprogs-y += relocs
relocs-objs     := relocs_32.o relocs_64.o relocs_common.o
PHONY += relocs
relocs: $(obj)/relocs
    @:
```

If someone knows what this error means?

Comment: Is this instruction for Ubuntu or what?

Comment: Hi, It is for Ubuntu, but an old version 6.0.6.

Comment: Old version of what?

Comment: @Pilot6 The driver included when sold was labeled for Ubuntu 6.0.6. Mine is 20.04. I think it is a mismatch in version after trying to figure that out. Waiting for the seller's response. I am going to close this. Thanks.